# Java subclass method is getting ignored

Tags: java, inheritance, types, type-conversion, extends

I have these classes

```
abstract class Person{
public void join(Lecture lec){System.out.println("Joining "+lec);}
public void join(OnlineLecture lec){System.out.println("Joining "+lec);}
}
class Student extends Person{
public void join(Lecture lec){System.out.println("Student joining "+lec);}
}
class Teacher extends Person{
public void join(OnlineLecture lec){System.out.println("Teacher joining "+lec);}
}
class Lecture{
public void addAttendant(Person p){p.join(this);}
public String toString(){return "a lecture";}
}
class OnlineLecture extends Lecture{
public String toString(){return "an online lecture";}
}
```

and then in main class I have this

```
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args){
Person p1=new Student();
Person p3=new Teacher();
Student p4=new Student();
OnlineLecture lec3=new OnlineLecture();
lec3.addAttendant(p1);
lec3.addAttendant(p3);
lec3.addAttendant(p4);
}
}
```

Why I get this:

```
Student joining an online lecture
Joining an online lecture
Student joining an online lecture
```

instead of this:

```
Joining an online lecture
Teacher joining an online lecture
Joining an online lecture
```

If I pass an OnlineLecture instance, why is the code behaving like it's a Lecture instance? Teacher class overrided join(OnlineLecture lec) but the one from the parent class is still getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only class `Lecture` defines `addAttendant(Person p)`. So the `this` in

```
public void addAttendant(Person p) {
 p.join(this);
}
```

will always be a `Lecture`.

And since `Student` overrides `join(Lecture lec)`, this overridden method gets called while `lec3.addAttendant(p1);` since `p1` is a `Student` and `lec3` is a `Lecture` too.

`Teacher` only overrides `join(OnlineLecture lec)` but not `join(Lecture lec)`. And `lec3.addAttendant(p3);` calls `Lecture.addAttendant(Person p)` where `p` == `p3` is a `Teacher` but `this` in `p.join(this);` is a `Lecture` but not a `OnlineLecture`. That's why `Teacher.join(OnlineLecture lec)` cannot be called since `this` is not a `OnlineLecture` but a `Lecture`. So `Person.join(Lecture lec)` gets called.

Not really clear what shall be achieved using that complex inheritance and nested method calling. So this is only the description of what is going on.

Comment: Ok the first line of your answer is what I was missing. Now it's clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the `join()` signature being more strongly typed in `Person` than `Student`
As `Student` only override for `Lecture` in

```java
  public void join(Lecture lec){System.out.println("Student joining "+lec);}
```

The method used comes from parent class `Person`

```java
  public void join(OnlineLecture lec){System.out.println("Joining "+lec);}
```

As a solution, override correctly `join` in `Student` class with the given signature

```java
public void join(OnlineLecture lec)
```

Comment: the parent method prints Joining + lec though. So why in the first line I get "Student joining" + lec, if the parent method is the one getting called? Also Teacher() overrides join(OnlineLecture lec) but the parent method is still getting called.